# Bulk editing hides actions in material-table

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I'm using material-table in react js (https://material-table.com/#/).

Now I confront with an problem which is identical to this issue:  https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/2561,

**Describe the problem:
When bulk editing table, icons from the actions column disappear.**

**To Reproduce:
https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable
Go to "Bulk Edit Example"
Click on the "Edit All" pencil icon.
"Delete" button from Actions column disappears.
Expected behavior
Buttons in the action column stay visible in bulk edit mode.**

Any ideas or help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I think that's intentional, because you should not be able to delete anything ( even by mistake ) while editing something

Comment: @GayatriDipali Thanks for your opinion. Yes maybe that's a reason why the authors hide such action icons while opening bulk editing. But I'm curious about whether there is some solution to change this setting (Actually in my case, I have both add & delete icon in each row, and I want these icons still appear while bulk editing, so uses can also choose to add row or even delete row without closing the bulk editing icon first. In other words, I want a full-edit mode which allows  bulk update / add / delete simultaneously.)